# Time stamping every line of stdout

Tags: bash, shell

I'm looking for a advice.

I would like to have a timestamp for each line of my stdout.

So that when I use a script that returns a lot of information I can trace each return with the time and the day.

I can easily add a timestamp for each command i make but i can't get it for each return.

Thanks !

Comment: You could modify the program which outputs a line so that it adds the time stamp. Another alternative would be to cause the programs to write to stdout unbuffered, and then use a program such as [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to intercept the output and add the timestamps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not re-invent the wheel, use an existing solution. The `moreutils` package which is available on nearly all distros contains `ts`. Which was written exactly for your use case:

```
$ cmd | ts
```

For example:

```
$ (echo a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 3; echo c; sleep 2; echo d; sleep 1) | ts
Feb 09 14:34:51 a
Feb 09 14:34:52 b
Feb 09 14:34:55 c
Feb 09 14:34:57 d
```

**Note**: When writing to a pipe, instead of a terminal, the program's output will be block buffered by the libc instead of being line buffered as per default when writing to a terminal.

That means that the timestamps would be of that moment when the stdout gets flushed, which isn't necessarily the same as the moment when a line was written. `stdbuf` can be used on Linux to enforce line buffered output:

```
stdbuf -oL cmd | ts
```

PS: On MacOS there is `unbuffer` for the same purpose

Comment: ts is not available on Centos 7 "out of the box"

Comment: @RamanSailopal Of course, it's in the `moreutils` package as I mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the output of your program through `read` and append the date, line by line:

```
your_programm | while read l; do echo "$(date): $l"; done
```

Of course you can then also format the output of `date`.

Answer (score 0):

There are buffering issues to worry about, but it is often sufficient to do:

```
cmd | perl -ne 'printf "%s: %s",  scalar localtime(), $_'
```

But I get the impression you are looking for a more general solution to intercept all commands.  Perhaps something like:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/fifo
$ perl -ne 'print scalar localtime(), ": ", $_' < /tmp/fifo &
[1] 57567
$ exec > /tmp/fifo
$ echo foo
Tue Feb  9 13:34:04 2021: foo
$ echo bar
Tue Feb  9 13:34:12 2021: bar
```